# Creating multiple rooms in Vaadin Web chat

Tags: java, web, vaadin, chat

i`m doing a project based on Spring Boot and i integrated Vaadin in my project for purpose of writing chat. And i managed to write a chat, where multiple users can talk with each other. But how can i create a multiple rooms , for instance: one is Henry - Lara and second is Henry - John , and save this all rooms at one page, to let Henry switch between them. How can i do that? Here is my 2 classes of group chat. I would appreciate any help, if i even would need to change the whole code

Here is the code:

```
package ua.socialnetwork.message;


import com.github.rjeschke.txtmark.Processor;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.*;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H3;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import ua.socialnetwork.security.SecurityUser;

@Route("/chat")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final Storage storage;
    private Registration registration;

    private Grid<Storage.ChatMessage> grid;
    private VerticalLayout chat;
    private VerticalLayout login;
    private String user = "";

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    //ToDO put in try catch
    SecurityUser u = (SecurityUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

    public MainView(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;

        buildLogin();
        buildChat();
    }

    //ToDO remove login form
    private void buildLogin() {
        login = new VerticalLayout() {{
            TextField field = new TextField();
            field.setValue(u.getFullName());
            field.setReadOnly(true);
            field.setPlaceholder("Please, introduce yourself");
            add(
                    field,
                    new Button("Login") {{
                        addClickListener(click -> {
                            login.setVisible(false);
                            chat.setVisible(true);
                            user = field.getValue();
                            storage.addRecordJoined(user);
                        });
                        addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
                    }}
            );
        }};
        add(login);
    }

    private void buildChat() {
        chat = new VerticalLayout();
        add(chat);
        chat.setVisible(false);

        grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setItems(storage.getMessages());
        grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(message -> new Html(renderRow(message))))
                .setAutoWidth(true);

        TextField field = new TextField();

        chat.add(
                grid,
                new HorizontalLayout() {{
                    add(
                            field,
                            new Button("➡") {{
                                addClickListener(click -> {
                                    storage.addRecord(user, field.getValue());
                                    field.clear();
                                });
                                addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
                            }}
                    );
                }}
        );
    }

    public void onMessage(Storage.ChatEvent event) {
        if (getUI().isPresent()) {
            UI ui = getUI().get();
            ui.getSession().lock();
            ui.beforeClientResponse(grid, ctx -> grid.scrollToEnd());
            ui.access(() -> grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll());
            ui.getSession().unlock();
        }
    }

    private String renderRow(Storage.ChatMessage message) {
        if (message.getName().isEmpty()) {
            return Processor.process(String.format("_User **%s** is just joined the chat!_", message.getMessage()));
        } else {
            return Processor.process(String.format("**%s**: %s", message.getName(), message.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        registration = storage.attachListener(this::onMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        registration.remove();
    }
}
```

And here is another

```
package ua.socialnetwork.message;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

@Component
public class Storage {
    @Getter
    private Queue<ChatMessage> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ComponentEventBus eventBus = new ComponentEventBus(new Div());

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class ChatMessage {
        private String name;
        private String message;
    }

    public static class ChatEvent extends ComponentEvent<Div> {
        public ChatEvent() {
            super(new Div(), false);
        }
    }

    public void addRecord(String user, String message) {
        messages.add(new ChatMessage(user, message));
        eventBus.fireEvent(new ChatEvent());
    }

    public void addRecordJoined(String user) {
        messages.add(new ChatMessage("", user));
        eventBus.fireEvent(new ChatEvent());
    }

    public Registration attachListener(ComponentEventListener<ChatEvent> messageListener) {
        return eventBus.addListener(ChatEvent.class, messageListener);
    }

    public int size() {
        return messages.size();
    }
}
```

I know that it`s very simple, but still.

Comment: You could put multiple storages in a map and use that as your container for the "channels". Or you could filter the messages per channel and make that part of the message. I currently fail to see how that is "vaadin specific", so please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Actually i havent even tried that, because i absolutely have no idea how to do that. The thing is somehow create different thread with different room in each one. But how to implement that, i have no idea at all.